# var x=document.getElementById("mytext").value;Why i change the value to innerHTMl or innerText,it do not work?

Tags: javascript, input

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="mytext">
        <input type="button" onclick="myfuction()" value="click">

        <script type="text/javascript">
         //the problem is here,why the value is ok?but innerText don't
            function myfuction() {
                var a = document.getElementById("[mytext][1]").value;
                alert(a);
            }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

I want to enter text in the input box, and I will be prompted by clicking the button.

Comment: Selector is wrong, try `var a = document.getElementById("mytext").value;`

Comment: You seem to have tried to embed/link an image inside of a code block, which causes this weird `[mytext][1]`. If that is not intended, please fix.

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) works on the `ID` attribute of the element.

```js
function myfuction() {
  var a = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
  alert(a);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mytext">
<input type="button" onclick="myfuction()" value="click">
```